# Why urlencode function does not render valid url

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-routing

In my laravel 5.8 app I make image generation with action in image soutce, as :

```
     <img src="/show_banner_image/{{ $nextActiveBanners['id'] }}/{{ urlencode($nextActiveBanners['text']) }}/{{ urlencode($nextActiveBanners['url']) }}/{{
$nextActiveBanners['view_type'] }}/">
```

But if url have value “https://www.php.net” I got 404 error as

with routes/web.php :

```
Route::get('/show_banner_image/{banner_id}/{banner_text}/{banner_url}/{banner_view_type}', ['as' => 'site.viewImage', 'uses' => 'HomeController@test2']); //app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php
```

I got invalid url. I thought urlencode must salve it, bit looks like not...
How to correct it?

Comment: 404 is not always a wrong route / url definition / missmatch - it might be that it does not match your given banner id for example (or if you use findOrFail). Have you checked if the code actually reaches your controller? maybe just dd something in the test2 method of your HomeController to check it. Also - can you provide an example of the actual src value - just look at the dom and copy paste the result here please.

Comment: If to replace value "https://www.php.net" with value "php.net” it works ok. i suppose urlencode does not encode "//" symbols, as I have src with value "http://local-votes.com/show_banner_image/1/PHP+site/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.php.net/2/"

Comment: Sure it does, @PetroGromovo. `urlencode('https://www.php.net/')` generates `https%3A%2F%2Fwww.php.net%2F`. Take a close look at the URL you wind up on in the 404 page, and the HTML source of the page the `<img>` tag is on. Maybe consider removing the trailing `/` on your image tag?